# wifi driver error - Ubuntu 18.04 for bcm4365 - Dell Vostro

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04, broadcom, network-drive

I tried running the following commands and it did not work.

- sudo apt update
- sudo apt install bcmwl-kernal-source
- sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernal-source sudo
- modprobe -r b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcsmac bcma
- sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

  - sudo modprobe -r b43
  - sudo modprobe b43
  - sudo rfkill unblock all

[Results for version lspci -nn -d 14e4:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg7MJ.png)

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl`?

Comment: Hello. I got the fix. I had to manually go to software&updates --Additional drivers and enable my broadcom.